# Makefile "No such file or directory" when command is in PATH

Tags: unix, makefile, path

I'm trying to write a Makefile in such a way that all of the steps in my recipe can call scripts a list of directories. As an example, I have node commands that are in a node_modules/.bin directory, but there could just as well be Python commands from a Python virtual environment as well, etc.

I have `node` installed, as well as TypeScript installed via npm in my `/node_modules`. Given my directory `/tmp/test123`, I wrote the following Makefile at `/tmp/test123/Makefile` as an example:

```
PATH = /tmp/test123/node_modules/.bin:$(PATH)

.PHONY: compile
compile:
    env | grep "PATH"
    tsc --help
```

However, if I try to run it, it outputs:

```
$ make compile
env | grep "PATH"
PATH=/tmp/test123/node_modules/.bin:... # the rest of my PATH
tsc --help
make: tsc: No such file or directory
make: *** [compile] Error 1
```

But if I change the last line to `cd . && tsc --help`, then `compile` runs successfully.

Why is make unable to find the `tsc` command in the PATH? Why do I need to run `cd . &&` in front of it? Is there any better workaround than writing `cd . &&` in front of all of my recipe steps?

Comment: You should use `PATH := /tmp/test123/node_modules/.bin:$(PATH)` rather than running `shell`.  However, I can't reproduce your problem.  What version of GNU make are you using, and what operating system?

Comment: @MadScientist I'm using GNU Make 3.81 on macOS Big Sur 11.4. Removing the call to shell doesn't fix it - but I'll incorporate the correction.

Comment: I'm assuming that if you replace `tsc --help` with the fully-qualified path `/tmp/test123/node_modules/.bin/tsc --help` it works properly?  If so I can only suggest you get a better version of GNU make, perhaps via MacPorts or similar.  The version of GNU make that MacOS provides is known to be buggy.